# Run a script on Raspbian startup but not on terminal open

Tags: raspbian, bash

I have added a command in `.bashrc` to run a script at startup of my Raspberry Pi, but everytime I open a new terminal the same script executes again.

Is there any way I can make this script run only on startup / power up and not each time I open a new terminal?

Comment: Use a cron job and the @reboot option (man cron, man 5 crontab).

Comment: @joan Can you please provide an answer with a few more details? I'm not sure what a cron job actually is.

Comment: @joan's answer is correct. `bashrc` is a configuration file for the bash shell, which means it gets called every time a bash terminal is started.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a cron job.

Cron is used when you want to schedule jobs to run at specific times, e.g. every hour, every Sunday at 3 a.m.  It stores the details in a table for each user called a crontab which is read during boot.

One of the "times" you can specify is at a reboot.

To list your crontab use the command

```
crontab -l
```

To edit/create your crontab use the command

```
crontab -e
```

On occasion you might want to run a script as root in which case precede the previous two commands with sudo.

Use the following commands for help

```
man cron
man -5 crontab
```

In your case you need a simple job like I use to mount a NFS disk at boot.  My crontab contains the following:

```
@reboot              (sleep 60; /bin/mount /code)&
```

You need to use crontab -e and add the following to your crontab

```
@reboot              /home/pi/script
```

where /home/pi/script is the full path to the script you want to run.

Comment: Can you specify it to run every time it boots instead of only at a reboot?

Comment: @reboot means when the Linux system is started (usually from power-up).  What distinction are you making?